Derived Koszul complex
Let $X$ be a projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$ and $V$ be a vector bundle over $X$. Let $\pi: V\to X$ be the natural projection.
Let $i: X\to V$ be the zero section map. Let $V^\vee$ be the dual bundle of $V$. We have well-known Koszul complex (which is a resolution of $i_*\mathcal{O}_X$ by locally free sheaves over $V$) as follows:
$$\cdots\rightarrow\pi^*(\wedge^{2}V^\vee)\rightarrow\pi^*(\wedge^1V^\vee)\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_V\rightarrow i_*\mathcal{O}_X.$$
Now we replace $V$ by a bounded complex of vector bundles over $X$, say $\mathcal{E}:=\cdots\to V_{-2}\to V_{-1}\to V_{0}\to 0$. We have an derived scheme $V_\mathcal{E}$ affine over $X$ associated with $\mathcal{E}$. Denote by $\pi_\mathcal{E}$ and $i_\mathcal{E}$ be the natural projection and zero section map respectively.
Problem: What about the "Koszul resolution" (if exists) of
the sheaf $(i_{\mathcal{E}})_*\mathcal{O}_X$over the derived scheme $V_{\mathcal{E}}$?
Any comments or references are welcome, thanks!

The same construction (interpreted as ${\rm Sym}(\pi^* V^{\vee} [1]) \to^\sim  i_* \mathcal O_X$) works for complexes, although it is not a bounded resolution unless $V$ is concentrated in even degrees.  Here I am taking the symmetric power wrt the Koszul sign rule.

@Phil Tosteson Thanks for your comments. Can you show me a reference please? By the way, Is the Thom isomorphism still hold in this case? Thank you! :)

A slight generalization of "usual" Koszul complex is summarized in Illusie's thesis Complexe Cotangent et Deformations I, 4.3.1.2 & 4.3.1.3 & 4.3.1.6 (where the result is attributed to Quillen):

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, and $u\colon E\to F$ a map of $A$-modules. The Koszul algebra $\DeclareMathOperator\Kos{Kos}\Kos(u)$ is the differential bi-graded algebra $\bigwedge E\otimes\DeclareMathOperator\Sym{Sym}\Sym F$, with derivation $d$ of degree $(-1,1)$, such that $d(x\otimes1)=1\otimes ux$ and $d(1\otimes y)=0$.
Let $A$ be a commutative ring, and $0\to E\xrightarrow uF\xrightarrow vG\to0$ be an exact sequence of flat $A$-modules. Then the canonical map $\Kos(u)\to\Kos(0\to G)=\Sym G$ is a quasi-isomorphism.

One can generalize this to the situation that $E\to F\to G$ is a distinguished triangle in the derived category $D^{\le0}(A)$: one first pick a resolution $u_*\colon E_*\to F_*$ of $E\to F$, where each $E_*$ and $F_*$ are flat, and each map $u_*$ is injective. Using the Dold–Kan correspondence, one gets a simplicial flat resolution $u_\bullet\colon E_\bullet\to F_\bullet$ of $u$, which allows you to cook up a simplicial Koszul algebra $\Kos(u_\bullet)$. You can then totalize to get what you want. This is basically what happens in the proof of 4.3.2.1.
A homotopy invariant description could be found in [Lurie, Spectral Algebraic Geometry Prop 25.2.4.1].
In char $0$, the situation is simpler: you do not have to pass along the Dold–Kan correspondence, but manipulate CDGA's directly.
